# Loop fetch the certain adjacent rows in file with shell

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I have the following file, which contains the dependencies I need to git clone into local directory.

```
The sequence of lines is fixed, but the empty line isn't.
[dependencies]                                                                                                                                                                                               
[dependencies.module_a]
install_path = "folder_a"
  
[dependencies.module_a.git]
rev = "commit id"
url = "git url"
   
[dependencies.module_b]
install_path = "folder_b"
  
[dependencies.module_b.git]
rev = "commit id"
url = "git url"
 
[dependencies.module_c]
install_path = "folder_a"
 
[dependencies.module_c.git]
rev = "commit_id"
url = "git url"
```

I want to fetch the certain adjacent rows(install_path, rev and url) in loop, so I can use `git clone -b rev url install_path` to achive batch git clone. But I only find the way of reading file line by line.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
filename="$1"
while read -r line; do
    name="$line"
    echo "Name read from file - $name"
done < "$filename"
```

Comment: Where does the file format come from? Are the line numbers part of the file? Is the sequence of lines fixed, i.e.  `[dependencies.*]`, `install_path`, empty line, `[dependencies.*.git]`, `rev`, `url`, empty line or EOF? Please [edit] your question to add this information. You could read the file line-by-line, on `[dependencies.*]` (with a single dot) clear the variables, ignore `[dependencies.*.git]` (with two dots), parse all `key = value` lines, and when you have read all 3 values run the `git` command.

Answer (score 2):

File: `depsgit.sh`

```sh
#! /bin/bash

DEPS_FILENAME="$1"

checkDepsFlag() {
    local -i FLAG=$1
    local -i N_LINE=$2
    local    LINE="$3"
    if [[ ${FLAG} -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "No '[dependencies]' line before line #${N_LINE}: '${LINE}'" >&2
        exit 2
    fi
}

checkDepFlag() {
    local -i FLAG=$1
    local -i N_LINE=$2
    local    LINE="$3"
    if [[ ${FLAG} -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "No '[dependencies.<module>]' line before line #${N_LINE}: '${LINE}'" >&2
        exit 3
    fi
}

checkGitFlag() {
    local -i FLAG=$1
    local -i N_LINE=$2
    local    LINE="$3"
    if [[ ${FLAG} -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "No '[dependencies.<module>.git]' line before line #${N_LINE}: '${LINE}'" >&2
        exit 4
    fi
}

useData() {
    local MODULE="$1"
    local GIT_MODULE="$2"
    local DATA_INSTALL_PATH="$3"
    local DATA_REV="$4"
    local DATA_URL="$5"
    echo "* Doing what you want with Git, Nexus, Sonar..."
    echo "  * MODULE='${MODULE}'"
    echo "  * GIT_MODULE='${GIT_MODULE}'"
    echo "  * DATA_INSTALL_PATH='${DATA_INSTALL_PATH}'"
    echo "  * DATA_REV='${DATA_REV}'"
    echo "  * DATA_URL='${DATA_URL}'"
    # like:
    #git clone -b "${DATA_REV}" "${DATA_URL}" "${DATA_INSTALL_PATH}"
}

declare -i N_LINE=0
declare -i FLAG_DEPS=0
declare -i FLAG_DEP=0
declare -i FLAG_GIT=0
declare GIT_MODULE=
declare MODULE=
declare KEY=
declare VALUE=
declare DATA_INSTALL_PATH=
declare DATA_REV=
declare DATA_URL=
while read LINE; do
    N_LINE=$(( ++N_LINE ))
    if [[ "${LINE}" == "[dependencies]" ]]; then
        FLAG_DEPS=1
        #echo "Dependencies..."
    elif [[ "${LINE}" =~ ^\[dependencies\..*\.git\]$ ]]; then
        checkDepsFlag ${FLAG_DEPS} ${N_LINE} "${LINE}"
        checkDepFlag  ${FLAG_DEP} ${N_LINE} "${LINE}"
        GIT_MODULE="${LINE#[dependencies.}"
        GIT_MODULE="${GIT_MODULE%.git]}"
        #echo "   - GIT_MODULE='${GIT_MODULE}'"
        FLAG_GIT=1
        DATA_REV=
        DATA_URL=
    elif [[ "${LINE}" =~ ^\[dependencies\..*\]$ ]]; then
        checkDepsFlag ${FLAG_DEPS} ${N_LINE} "${LINE}"
        MODULE="${LINE#[dependencies.}"
        MODULE="${MODULE%]}"
        #echo " - MODULE='${MODULE}'"
        FLAG_DEP=1
        DATA_INSTALL_PATH=
    elif [[ "${LINE}" =~ ^[^=]+\ =\ \".*\"$ ]]; then
        checkDepsFlag ${FLAG_DEPS} ${N_LINE} "${LINE}"
        KEY="${LINE%% =*}"
        VALUE="${LINE#*= }"
        VALUE="${VALUE#\"}"
        VALUE="${VALUE%\"}"
        #echo "     - KEY='${KEY}'"
        #echo "     - VALUE='${VALUE}'"
        case "${KEY}" in
            "install_path")
                checkDepFlag ${FLAG_DEP} ${N_LINE} "${LINE}"
                DATA_INSTALL_PATH="${VALUE}"
            ;;
            "rev")
                checkGitFlag ${FLAG_GIT} ${N_LINE} "${LINE}"
                DATA_REV="${VALUE}"
            ;;
            "url")
                checkGitFlag ${FLAG_GIT} ${N_LINE} "${LINE}"
                DATA_URL="${VALUE}"
            ;;
            *)
                echo "Unknown key def line #${N_LINE}: '${LINE}'" >&2
                exit 1
            ;;
        esac
    elif [[ "${LINE}" =~ ^\ *$ ]]; then
        # ignore blank lines
        :
    else
        echo "Unknown syntax line #${N_LINE}: '${LINE}'" >&2
        exit 1
    fi
    if [[ ${FLAG_DEPS} -eq 1 ]] && [[ ${FLAG_DEP} -eq 1 ]] && [[ ${FLAG_GIT} -eq 1 ]]; then
        if [[ -n "${MODULE}" ]] && [[ -n "${GIT_MODULE}" ]]; then
            if [[ -n "${DATA_INSTALL_PATH}" ]] && [[ -n "${DATA_REV}" ]] && [[ -n "${DATA_URL}" ]]; then
                useData "${MODULE}" "${GIT_MODULE}" "${DATA_INSTALL_PATH}"  "${DATA_REV}" "${DATA_URL}"
                # reset
                MODULE=
                GIT_MODULE=
                DATA_INSTALL_PATH=
                DATA_REV=
                DATA_URL=
                MODULE=
                GIT_MODULE=
                FLAG_DEP=0
                FLAG_GIT=0
            fi
        fi
    fi
# echo command usefull if no LF at EOF
done < <(cat "${DEPS_FILENAME}"; echo)
```

Use simple:

```sh
$ depsgit.sh myprojet.deps
```

*Sorry for this long response*